# Complex fetch-request for NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Here's a simplified look for my model:

- Media has property 'status' that can be either 'Uploading' or 'Uploaded'.
- User has property 'syncStatus' that be either 'NotSynced' or 'Synced'.
- ObjectX is a 'linking' object between User and Media
- User has to-many relationship to ObjectX
- ObjectX has to-one relationship to Media

Is there any way to use NSFetchedResultsController to fetch all Users that are 'Synced' and whose all media are 'Uploaded'? It would have to update its content also when 'Media' status is changed so that new User should be fetched. I've heard NSFetchedResultsController doesn't work well with such complex fetch requests.

[image: Model Graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be more practical to model the fetch by denormalizing the data.  You can add a 'status' Boolean to User indicating whether all their Media is uploaded.

This would be much more efficient than having to aggregate the status of each object's model.

Comment: How can I add such Boolean to User so that it always keep itself up to date?

Comment: You'd update the User status when inserting or updating Media.  For example, if you add new Media, and it's status is 'Uploading', you'd also change its object's User.status to 'Uploading'.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the user should have another status flag (or use the synced status flag). You can update this at a central point by overriding the setter in the media object.

```
-(void)setStatus:(MediaStatus)value {
  [self willChangeValueForKey:@"status"];
  [self setPrimitiveStatus:value];
  [self didChangeValueForKey:@"status"];

  // get status of other media objects
  NSSet *objects = self.objectx.user.objects;
  NSSet *updatingObjects = 
     [objects filteredSetUsingPredicate:
     [NSPredicate predicatesWithFormat:@"media.status = %@", kUpdatingStatus]];
  self.objectx.user.updating = 
     updatingObjects.count ? kUpdatingStatus : kUpdatedStatus;
}
```

Still, an appropriate FRC predicate should also work. E.g., to only show updated users, something along the lines of

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"any objectx.media.status = $@", kUpdatedStatus]
```

Comment: Thanks for providing code :)  There's an edge case we missed.  When a deleted Media's status was updating, and the remaining Media are all updated, the User status should change to updated.